Why is "message receiving processing" so jarring?
I am proofreading a document (basically concerned with network protocols) that has been translated from an Asian language, which has resulted in the term "message receiving processing".
This refers to the processing that is conducted by a node on the network after a message has been received. It works fine in the original language, but I am having difficulty articulating exactly why I immediately want to reject this "message receiving processing".
Can anyone explain to me how this is grammatically incorrect? I suppose "message-receiving processing" would kind of work but it still feels awkward. I would have used "Processing of received message" or similar, I guess.

Yes, this looks like a mistranslation, especially if you are certain that the processing is done after the message has been received. Perhaps received-message processing or even simply message processing if the step are in logical order, e.g., "reception, processing, reply"

I would have said input message(s) process.

Please give is the full sentence that the phrase occurs in!

There is an associated phenomenon called the 'double -ing constraint', which has been covered on ELU before [F.E.'s Answer]:

Some verbs that license gerund-participial complements cannot
themselves occur in the gerund-participle form when they have such a
complement. Compare:
i a. They started quarreling. - - - b. (*) They are starting
quarreling. [CaGEL]

This is not a hard-and-fast prohibition; indeed, CGEL mentions

iii a. We considered buying one. - - - b. We are considering buying
one.

as a clear exception, and some, like


?The lawn is always needing mowing.


are of debated acceptability.
That said, in

'message receiving processing'

we have a compound premodifier rather than a catenation of verb forms.
But this sounds clumsy (and perhaps the double -ing constraint does inform the situation to some extent, by association).
There is another rule-of-thumb, that the 'prototypical' noun is to be preferred to the ing-form synonym where there is no good reason to distinguish the two (and of course, where available). Possibly more so when the use is attributive. I'm sure this too has been covered on ELU.
There seems to be a clear alternative:

message reception processing.


I had mentally parsed the original to mean The message is receiving some sort of processing.

And should << double -ing >> have two hyphens before a noun?

But would you pair message reception processing with message sending processing? reception / sending vs. receiving / sending...

Message reception processing would also contradict the OP's knowledge that the processing is done after the message has been received. However, if correct, wouldn't a hyphen help: message-reception processing?

TH, We're moving from gas to nuclear. / 'Baking and pastry' seems an established expression. 'reading, writing, and arithmetic.' / 'spelling and punctuation.'  Ok, these ing-forms (and 'nuclear') are getting pretty nouny.  // DT,  I'd say 'message reception' is cohesive enough a collocation not to need a hyphen.

It’s a little bumpy, but it seems perfectly natural in context:

A classical command and control system mainly consists of the
following parts:

Message receiving processing: to receive all kinds of information
and classify them.
Message sending processing: to transfer all kinds of information.
Synthetic intelligence processing: to check,
correlate, and syncretize the information from all kinds of sensors
in multilevel in order to obtain the correct situation data of the
battlefield and the evaluation of the target threatening degree.
Synthetic display processing: to display the target synthetic
situation pictures, tables, and the results of aid decision-making.
Aid tactic processing: to accomplish the evaluation of the target
threatening degree and all kinds of tactic calculations, make the
aid decisions for the commanders, deploy the weapon system, and
generate all kinds of battle plans.


